# Умножение и деление чисел spinBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

у меня есть код в котором есть `spinBox` и `4 кнопки`.

```
При нажатии на pushButton число в spinBox должно умножиться на 2. 
При нажатии на pushButton_2 число в spinBox должно быть число 1. 
При нажатии на pushButton_3 число в spinBox должно быть число 95. 
При нажатии на pushButton_4 число в spinBox должно поделиться на 2.
```

example.py:

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 

class Ui_MainWindow(object): 
 def setupUi(self, MainWindow): 
 MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow") 
 MainWindow.resize(377, 395) 
 MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);") 
 self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) 
 self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget") 
 self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget) 
 self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 250, 221, 41)) 
 font = QtGui.QFont() 
 font.setFamily("Arial") 
 font.setPointSize(24) 
 self.spinBox.setFont(font) 
 self.spinBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);") 
 self.spinBox.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhDigitsOnly) 
 self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons) 
 self.spinBox.setMinimum(1) 
 self.spinBox.setMaximum(95) 
 self.spinBox.setStepType(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.DefaultStepType) 
 self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox") 
 self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) 
 self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 200, 75, 23)) 
 self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);") 
 self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton") 
 self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) 
 self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 200, 75, 23)) 
 self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);") 
 self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2") 
 self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) 
 self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 150, 75, 23)) 
 self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);") 
 self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3") 
 self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) 
 self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 150, 75, 23)) 
 self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);") 
 self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4") 
 MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 

 self.retranslateUi(MainWindow) 
 QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow) 

 def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow): 
 _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate 
 MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "...")) 
 self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "УДВОИТЬ")) 
 self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "МИНИМУМ(1)")) 
 self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "МАКСИМУМ(95)")) 
 self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ПОЛОВИНА")) 

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): 
 def __init__(self): 
 super().__init__() 
 self.setupUi(self) 

if __name__=="__main__": 
 app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
 window = ExampleApp() 
 window.show() 
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 

class Ui_MainWindow(object): 
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow): 
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow") 
        MainWindow.resize(377, 395) 
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);") 
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) 
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget") 
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget) 
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 250, 221, 41)) 
        font = QtGui.QFont() 
        font.setFamily("Arial") 
        font.setPointSize(24) 
        self.spinBox.setFont(font) 
        self.spinBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);") 
        self.spinBox.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhDigitsOnly) 
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons) 
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(1) 
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(95) 
        self.spinBox.setStepType(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.DefaultStepType) 
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox") 
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) 
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 200, 75, 23)) 
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);") 
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton") 
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) 
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 200, 75, 23)) 
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);") 
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2") 
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) 
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 150, 75, 23)) 
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);") 
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3") 
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) 
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 150, 75, 23)) 
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);") 
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4") 
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow) 
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow) 

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow): 
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate 
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "...")) 
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "УДВОИТЬ")) 
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "МИНИМУМ(1)")) 
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "МАКСИМУМ(95)")) 
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ПОЛОВИНА")) 


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.setupUi(self) 

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 2, 1, 1, 3)

        # При нажатии на pushButton_3 число в spinBox должно быть число 95.
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda :self.onClicked('95'))
        #При нажатии на pushButton_4 число в spinBox должно поделиться на 2.
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda :self.onClicked('/2'))
        # При нажатии на pushButton число в spinBox должно умножиться на 2
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda :self.onClicked('*2'))
        # При нажатии на pushButton_2 число в spinBox должно быть число 1
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda :self.onClicked('1'))

    def onClicked(self, value):
        if value == '95':
            self.spinBox.setValue(int(value))
        if value == '/2':
            self.spinBox.setValue(self.spinBox.value() / int(value[1:]))        
        if value == '*2':
            self.spinBox.setValue(self.spinBox.value() * int(value[1:]))        
        if value == '1':
            self.spinBox.setValue(int(value))        


if __name__ == "__main__": 
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
        window = ExampleApp() 
        window.show() 
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно законектить каждую кнопку со своей функцией.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(377, 395)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 250, 221, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.spinBox.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhDigitsOnly)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(1)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(95)
        self.spinBox.setStepType(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.DefaultStepType)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "УДВОИТЬ"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "МИНИМУМ(1)"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "МАКСИМУМ(95)"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ПОЛОВИНА"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.spinBox.setValue(self.spinBox.value()*2))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.spinBox.setValue(1))
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.spinBox.setValue(95))
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.spinBox.setValue(self.spinBox.value()/2))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, но я вас умоляю, не надо редактировать класс `Ui_MainWindow` вставьте строки `self.pushButton....clicked.connect(...)` в класс `ExampleApp`

Comment: @S.Nick исправил. Я просто привык, что у меня код, сгенерированный Qt в отдельном файле и его никак не трону )